# Why shouldn't LDAP support inequality searches on shadowExpire?

Tags: postfix, ldap, openldap, schema, shadow

When I try to search my OpenLDAP 2.4.42 server for `(shadowExpire<=18074)`, I get no results.  However, a search for `(shadowExpire=12671)` yields several results.

My ultimate goal is to periodically regenerate a Postfix map for [`check_recipient_access`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_recipient_access) to reject mail to expired accounts.

---

Looking at the server's [`/etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema`](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob;f=servers/slapd/schema/nis.schema;h=31b4eb8c11b2a339db2482dfc17e08b4d3a5f8f0;hb=e736c44a7c6a83bb03e52fa9c7dbddb71bf9eeaf#l85), I see:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.10 NAME 'shadowExpire'
        EQUALITY integerMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

This agrees with [RFC 2307 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307#page6), which specifies:

```
( nisSchema.1.10 NAME 'shadowExpire'
  EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX 'INTEGER' SINGLE-VALUE )
```

Both of those suggest that `shadowExpire` only supports equality searches only.

However, [RFC 2307bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-02#section-3) has:

```
( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.10 NAME 'shadowExpire'
    EQUALITY integerMatch
    ORDERING integerOrderingMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

… which has `ORDERING integerOrderingMatch`, allowing the inequality search to work.

---

Can I hack my server's `nis.schema` to include `ORDERING integerOrderingMatch`?  The underlying representation would still be an [`INTEGER`](https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27.html), so it should be harmless, right? (Despite the warning in the [OpenLDAP Administrator's Guide](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/schema.html#Distributed%20Schema%20Files) that says "you should not modify any of the schema items defined in provided files.)

Answer (score 0):

You correctly analyzed the missing ordering matching rule.

However you should not alter schema files shipped with OpenLDAP like `nis.schema`. But you could use an alternative schema file `rfc2307bis.schema` instead. Some Linux distributions already ship this file.

Note that usage of `nis.schema` and `rfc2307bis.schema` is mutually exclusive.